# JSON.parse called implicitly?

Tags: php, javascript, json

I have JSON coming from my server into my javascript like so -

```
<script>
   var resp = <?php  echo getjsonFromServer() . ';'?> 
   resp=JSON.parse(resp);
   displayStats(resp);
</script>
```

This yields an error 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token o' and when I check the console I see that the response has already been JSON parsed . Meaning I shouldn't have tried to JSON.parse an already parsed answer .

My question is - how come  ? Who parsed my JSON for me ? I'm used to call JSON.parse whenever I get JSON from the server , e.g ajax calls . Why is it not the same here ?

Note - My PHP is something like this

```
header('"Content-Type":application/json');
$js = json_encode($js);
echo $js;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at your generated source.

You're echoing raw JSON, so your source looks like

```
var resp = { "property": "value", ... };
```

That's an object literal, not a string

Comment: I edited my question to show what my php does. Just to be clear - is the header('"Content-Type":application/json'); responsible to tell the browser - don't treat this as text/string but as an object? Had I left out that line then would I need to call JSON.parse ?

Comment: @Joel_Blum: That has nothing to do with this.  If your page includes that header, it's actually lying – your page is HTML, not JSON.  And, no.

Comment: So I'm confused , when does one need to use JSON.parse ? It seems all one has to do is json_encode on his server , and then just catch the response into a javascript variable and viola . Do you ever have to JSON.parse JSON coming from the server ?

Comment: @Joel_Blum: You need to call `JSON.parse` if your **Javascript** code has a string containing JSON data (eg, the result of an AJAX request).  Your page has a Javascript object literal, not a string.

Comment: Hoping not to drive you crazy , I think I'm getting there : Why do I have to JSON.parse the same exact response from the server if it's an ajax call ? I mean lets say I ask for the same JSON by an ajax and try this - var resp = xmlhttp.responseText;   Now resp is just a string and I DO have to use JSON.parse . Can you drive the point home by explaining the difference?

Comment: @Joel_Blum Text that's included inside `<script>` tags on the page is interpreted as JavaScript. So what looks like JSON is automatically parsed as a JavaScript object literal (which works because JSON is a subset of JavaScript's object literal syntax). Text from `xmlhttp.responseText` is just a string, not part of the program, so you need to tell JavaScript how to interpret it by calling `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Minor correction, @MatthewCrumley, in your last sentence: `JSON.parse`, not `JSON.stringify`. You want to parse it, not encode it again (which would make it double JSON encoded).

Comment: Oops, yes I definitely meant `JSON.parse`. Thanks @HutchMoore.

Answer (score 2):

It is not JSON. You are rendering plain old JavaScript.

```
<script>
   var resp = (<?php  echo getjsonFromServer() ?>); 
   displayStats(resp);
</script>
```

this should do it.

In case you wondering: adding brackets makes browser parse your code as object literal instead of a code block.

Comment: Wrong.  His code works fine with or without parentheses.  (The `=` forces it to be an expression).  He just can't call `JSON.parse` on an object.

Comment: @SLaks tough day at work? Perhaps "unnecessary" is a proper word here.

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't know that a php function is used to create the object. To the browser it is just javascript as if it was part of the source in the first place.